# Theoretical behaviour of RAM if single read/write error

Tags: memory, ecc, memory-error

The topic is *not* a broken RAM.

A good RAM can also have occasionally errors when reading/writing;
non-ECC RAMs more than ECC RAMs, but errors are possible with both types.

My question is, when can errors happen?
Read, write, both?

To be more specific, if i write once and read the same thing multiple times...
a) will i read either the good data all times, or if bad data, all times the same bad data
b) can i get different things with each read?

Comment: Really, any bit could be flipped at any time. A bit of cosmic radiation might hit it and flip a random bit. You don't have to be reading or writing when that happens - heck, you could not access that bit for a year and it could still have flipped in that time.

Comment: Well, aren´t i stupid. Somewhere in the back of my head, i knew that radiation can be a cause, but still i asked this ^^ I you make an answer, i will accept it right now